# Deriving relations for a hard sphere phase diagram

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, correlation-functions

In Torquato's Random Heterogeneous Materials, he has written
$$\frac{p}{\rho kT} = 1+2^{d-1}\eta g_2 (D^{+})$$
where $g_2(D^+)$ is the contact value from the right-side of the radial distribution function, and $\eta$ is a dimensionless reduced density.

After a couple lines, he states that for hard spheres, via the Ornstein-Zernike equation, we can rewrite the above equation in terms of the direct correlation function $c(r)$ as
$$\frac{p}{\rho kT} = 1+2^{d-1}\eta [c(D^+)-c(D^-)]$$

How does he reach this conclusion?

Ornstein-Zernike states that
$$h(r_{12}) = c(r_{12}) + \rho \int d\mathbf{r}_3 c(r_{13})h(r_{32})$$
which after a Fourier transform becomes
$$\hat{C} (\mathbf{k}) = \frac{\hat{H}(\mathbf{k})}{1+\rho \hat{H}(\mathbf{k})}$$

However, I don't see how to simplify this to the second equation he has. I would appreciate any advice you have.